# Custom Drawable border overlaps with App Bar Layout Header

Tags: android, android-custom-drawable

This is how my custom drawable looks by default.

[image]

But when scrolled, it overlaps with the AppBarLayout.

[image]

The code for the Drawable goes like this:

```
@Override
public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {

    // get drawable dimensions
    Rect bounds = getBounds();

    float width = bounds.right - bounds.left;
    float height = bounds.bottom - bounds.top;
    float w2 = width / 2;
    float h2 = height / 2;
    float radius = Math.min(w2, h2) - mStrokeWidth / 2;

    mPath.reset();
    mPath.addCircle(width / 2, height / 2, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
    canvas.clipPath(mPath);

    // draw background gradient

    float barHeight = height / themeColors.length;
    mRectF.left = 0;
    mRectF.top = 0;
    mRectF.right = width;
    mRectF.bottom = height;
    for (int i = 0; i < themeColors.length; i++) {
        mPaint.setColor(themeColors[i]);

        canvas.drawRect(0, i * barHeight, width, (i + 1) * barHeight, mPaint);
    }

    mRectF.set(0, 0, width, height);
    canvas.clipRect(mRectF, Region.Op.REPLACE);

    if (mStrokeWidth != 0)
        canvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, width / 2 - mStrokeWidth / 2, mStrokePaint);

}
```

Support Library Version: 25.3.1, 26.1.0

What I've tried:
- Different Region values for clipping path instead of REPLACE
- Clipping path rectangle first and then clipping circle.

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting my solution as answer.

The reason it was getting overlapped was because the canvas was getting clipped twice without saving it.

I removed this statement:

```
canvas.clipRect(mRectF, Region.Op.REPLACE);
```

and before clipping the canvas for the first time
i saved its state using

```
canvas.save();
canvas.clipPath(mPath);
```

and then when i was drawing the stroke, i need the original canvas so i restored it

```
canvas.restore();
if (mStrokeWidth != 0)
    canvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, width / 2 - mStrokeWidth / 2, mStrokePaint);
```

This fixed the issue.

Final Drawable Code:

```
@Override
public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {

    // get drawable dimensions
    Rect bounds = getBounds();

    float width = bounds.right - bounds.left;
    float height = bounds.bottom - bounds.top;
    float w2 = width / 2;
    float h2 = height / 2;
    float radius = Math.min(w2, h2) - mStrokeWidth / 2;

    mPath.reset();
    mPath.addCircle(width / 2, height / 2, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.clipPath(mPath);

    // draw background gradient

    float barHeight = height / themeColors.length;
    mRectF.left = 0;
    mRectF.top = 0;
    mRectF.right = width;
    mRectF.bottom = height;
    for (int i = 0; i < themeColors.length; i++) {
        mPaint.setColor(themeColors[i]);

        canvas.drawRect(0, i * barHeight, width, (i + 1) * barHeight, mPaint);
    }

    mRectF.set(0, 0, width, height);
    //canvas.clipRect(mRectF, Region.Op.REPLACE);
    canvas.restore();

    if (mStrokeWidth != 0)
        canvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, width / 2 - mStrokeWidth / 2, mStrokePaint);

}
```